# Kernel mean embeddings in Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces: linear kernel

Tags: hilbert-spaces, expected-value, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I'm reading on [kernel mean embeddings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09522.pdf), and I got stuck a small detail, but I cannot figure it out, so I'm asking it here :)

Some context, we are given a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space on a compact set $\mathcal{X}$ $H$ with kernel $k : \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ defined on $\mathcal{X}$. The **kernel mean embedding** is defined as (we don't worry for now under what conditions this is well defined, we will assume everything is nice at the moment)
\begin{align}
 \mu_{\mathbb{P}} := \int k(x,\cdot)\mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}(x).
\end{align}
On page 31, section 3.1.1, it is said that if we take $k(x,x') = \langle x,x\rangle$, the linear kernel, that then $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}$ ''becomes just the first moment of $\mathbb{P}$''.

**But here is my question:** I don't see why this is the case. When I work this out, I get
\begin{align}
 \mu_{\mathbb{P}} &= \int k(x,\cdot)\mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}(x),\\
&=  \int \langle x, \cdot\rangle\mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}(x).
\end{align}
Whereas the first moment, aka the expectation, is defined as
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathcal{X}} x \mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}(x)
\end{align}
And I do not see how I can get equality. I have tried to use **Lemma 3.1** in the text. Plugging in the identity operator for $f$ seems to do the job, but then I still do not see how $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}$ is the expectation. Another thing that comes to mind, the expectation is an element in a field, but $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}$ is an element in a Hilbert space. So how does it make sense to even state that $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}$ ''becomes'' the first moment, as these elements are in different spaces.

Thanks for any help!

**---------EDIT---------**

If we assume that $\left\lVert\mathcal{K}(X, \cdot)\right\rVert_H < \infty$, then $\mu_{\mathbb{P}}\in H$. Then, from **example 3.1**, we can conclude that
\begin{align}
 \mu_{\mathbb{P}}(t) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \langle x, t\rangle \mathbb{d}\mathbb{P}(x) = \langle \textbf{m}_{\mathbb{P}}(1),\textbf{t}\rangle.
\end{align}
But still, how to show this?

Comment: You need to use that the feature map of the linear kernel is the identity, i.e., $k(\cdot,x) =x$.

Comment: @Flo, thanks a lot for your answer! However, I am not sure how I can deduce this, could you elaborate on your comment, thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that $k(x,y) = \langle\phi(x), \phi(y)\rangle = x^Ty$, when $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$, so that then the feature map $\phi(x) = x$. But could you elaborate then why $k(\cdot, x) = x$?

Comment: One identifies the so-called canonical feature map by $k(\cdot,x) = \phi(x)$. Using this in your comment yields the result. For more information, consider the text around (2.6) in the article that you linked.